# Sigfox timeout on downlinks

Tags: c, embedded, iot

I'm working on a B-L072-LRWAN1 board

I'm having a problem where close to 50% of all the downlinks I send to my device are just not received and instead I get a `SFX_ERR_INT_GET_RECEIVED_FRAMES_TIMEOUT` (0x9B) from the `SIGFOX_API_send_frame` function even though the sigfox backend tells me that my downlink has been received and ACKED

My LQI varies between good and excellent so I dont think the problem is related to a bad connectivity

I would be very grateful to anyone who has at least an idea on what could be happening here

Thanks for your answers

Comment: Example causes: there is another device that sends packets at the same time. Your antenna is bad. Your device is parsing the messages too slow. The RX window timeouts are not what they should be.

Comment: Thanks for your propositions ! I've tried with other antennas and the problem is still here. I dont think my device is too slow since it does manages to get some messages correctly. What do you mean by the window timeouts are not what they should be ? how could I modify them ?